# How can List<T>.Item Property be O(1)? Typo?

Tags: c#, list, list-template

I'm implementing a priority queue and want to iterate through the list to insert at the right spot. In the documentation it states that C# `List<T>.Item` Property is O(1):
[`List<T>.Item` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g.

```
int retrivedValue = myIntList[5];
```

How is this possible since add also is O(1)? It's like eating the cookie and still have it. Normal lists in my head have O(n) for accessing an element.

Comment: `Add` is O(1) only as long as the capacity of the backing array suffices. If it needs to be expanded, the complexity is O(n).

Comment: @Heinzi It's **amortized** O(1).

Comment: @Heinzi When backing list has to be extended, it's content is copied using `Array.Copy` which copies entire array at once, so it's still *O(1)*.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek No, that operation is indeed O(n), because the array copy's speed is dependent on the amount of memory it needs to copy.  However, when amortizing these rare O(n) operations among the other O(1) operations it actually turns out that each add is O(1), not O(n).  So a single add is technically O(n), but n adds is actually *also* O(n), not O(n ^ 2).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a list in representation, as the documentation says, it *represents a typed list of objects that can be accessed by index*. Its elements can be accessed by index directly and does not require element-by-element traversal, ergo, it's time complexity to access an element is O(1). It's implemented internally as a dynamic array, the kind that doubles its size when it fills up (thanks to comments!).

You may be confusing it with [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is implemented as a linked list...

Comment: You seem to be saying that accessing the element is O(n) rather than O(1) is this correct or is this a typo? Your argument to me suggests O(1) which is why I thought it might be a typo.

Comment: I'd like to mention that the ability to access elements in the list based on index does not imply that the operation can be done in O(1). For example, the Java LinkedList allows retrieval based on index, but requires O(n) time.

Comment: Well, I meant directly without traversing the list... Which now that I mention it, it should be the main idea of my answer. Didn't know that about Java, sounds nice.

Comment: You are so correct! All the comments here did really help and the pointer to LinkedList is my next step since that exactly what i need.

Comment: This kind of did give me an idea. Is there any solution where it has a linked list with two stacks of used and not used nodes and then store all the nod in memory like in an array. This would reduce the need for  allocation and garbage collect if structs are used.

Comment: @user1814859, do you need to remove elements from the middle of your list? Do you care about the order of your list?

Comment: To be specific, it's implemented as a dynamic array, with the classic "double the size when it's about to be filled" strategy.

Answer (score 55):

The standard [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type is *backed* by an internal array with O(1) access performance.

List does *not* use a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) implementation.

Answer (score 23):

The `List<T>` is backed by an array.

The `Add` operation is O(1) *amortized across all adds*, meaning that most operations are O(1), but some are O(N). Whenever the backing array fills up it gets copied to a new array of double the size.

As an example of how it works, assume the backing array starts with 4 elements. The first 4 additions are O(1), but the 5th will have to copy the existing 4 elements and add the 5th, making it O(5). Adding elements 6, 7, and 8 are O(1), while adding element 9 will be O(9). Then elements 10-16 will also be O(1).

By the time you've added 16 elements to the array, you've done O(28) operations, making adding N elements take almost O(2N) operations. Thus, adding a single element is O(2) = O(1) on average.

Comment: I wish to expand a little bit on this. You should emphasize that *most* operations (adding) are O(1), not some, *some* is too weak. Also your final conclusion should be that adding a single element is O(2) = O(1) on average. (You forgot to divide by the fact that you have added N elements)

Comment: " making adding N elements take almost O(2N) operations. Thus, adding a single element is O(2N) = O(N) on average." what now, either its adding N or adding a single element...

Comment: -1. Big-O notation talks about asymptotic behaviour.  So I have to ask; when you say 'but the 5th will have to copy the existing 4 elements and add the 5th, making it O(5)' what is the opertation O(5) in respect to?  The correct wording is; 'once for every power of two operations we will need to do an operation with run time proportional to the current length of the list.  O(1+2+4+8+16+...+x^2)=O(2*x^2)=O(n^2), so only the final such operation is interesting.  This is an O(n) operation, and O(n+1+1+1+...(n ones))=O(2n)=O(n).  So we have O(n) time to make n insertions.

Comment: @Taemyr: Do you mean 2^x rather than x^2?

Comment: It would have been possible to design `List<T>` such that every append or indexing operation would take constant time, if when one doubles the size of the list, one keeps the previous list and, each time an item is added to the new list, an item is moved from the old one.  Once the list needs to be re-expanded, the old list may be abandoned.  This approach would end up doing the same work as `List<T>` does; the advantages `List<T>` has stem from the fact that items may be copied faster in bulk than piecemeal, and look-ups require examining one array rather than two.

Comment: @cHao Yes. It should be exponential.

Comment: @supercat Agreed assuming allocation of memory is a constant time operation.  In reality this should not be assumed.

Comment: @Taemyr: In terms of worst-case behavior, allocating a big chunk of memory is not necessarily any worse than allocating a minimal-sized `Object`, though implementations may vary of course; in any case, having the same `Append` operations which allocate memory *also* have to perform a bulk copy won't help things.  BTW, I wonder if any concurrent GC systems offer any way of atomically asking if a certain amount of heap space is instantly available and creating a new object if so (allowing programs to create new objects in advance of need, at times when there would be no delay)?

Comment: @Taemyr: I'm also curious how the performance of `List<T>` compares with what would be obtained if rather than just a `T[]` it used both a `T[]` (for up to 85K worth of objects) and a `T[][]` (for objects beyond that).  If the `T[][]` used fixed-sized sub-arrays, lookups would still be O(1), and insertions/deletions near the start O(n).

Comment: @supercat: I believe that allocating the memory is nearly free (it's the GC you pay for), but the initialization is O(N). If you ask for a 50k array, the runtime is going to write 50k of zeros before making it available to you.

Comment: @Gabe: From a worst-case perspective, a memory allocation which forces a garbage collection will take as long as a garbage collection.  I would expect that memory would get cleared out in bulk when space is reclaimed, rather than piecemeal as it is allocated, though either approach could be used.

Answer (score 12):

You might want to have a look at [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx) in order to understand and yet use the most suitable data structure.

Below is the summary table:

[image]

Comment: Nice one! :) Where is the source?

Comment: The source is within the answer :)

Answer (score 8):

You only have `O(n)` if you have to iterate across the *list* to retrive the item.

For this example you are accessing an internal array by index, so do not have to iterate.

Answer (score 6):

Despite attractive List Search complexity based on element index, I wonder if your needs might be better served by a SkipList  as described in [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379573%28VS.80%29.aspx#datastructures20_4_topic4) alluded to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697445/skiplistt-vs-dictionarytkey-tvalue), as the ordering priority is not unique.

#### Dynamically extending an Array for n insertions (n unbounded) is in fact O(n)

If an array backing of a list is doubled in size every time and n is allowed to grow without bound then the number of times the array will be re-allocated will be O(logn) and at each point will be size 2^k; k = 1,2,3...

[image]

#### `List<T>.Item versus List<T>.Contains`

Access to elements in a List is O(1) if the index is known, but to keep the correct order based on priority, you would need to either use some external ordering mechanism, or use **.Contains**, but that 2nd method is not O(1).

#### Skiplists have O(logn) Search complexity; allows a PriorityQueue O(logn) enqueue and O(1) dequeue

The idea is that a SkipList is a linked list with randomly inserted "fast forward" pointers to overcome a link list's O(n) Search complexity.  Every node has a height K and K next pointers.  Without going into detail, heights are distributed and the next() function selects the appropriate pointer in such a way to make the search O(logn).  However, the node to remove from the queue is always going to be at one end of the linked list.

#### Online behavior

Memory is finite and practically speaking a priority queue is not going to grow forever.  One could argue that the queue grows to a certain size and then never gets reallocated.  But then, does it shrink?  If the list becomes fragmented, a shrink operation sounds even more costly than the grow operation.  If shrink is supported, then the cost will be paid every time the List grows too small and then subsequently the grow cost will be paid when the List grows too large.  If it's not supported then the memory associated with the largest queue size will remain allocated.  This being a priority queue, it does in fact sound possible that a queue could grow as work is fed into it, then shrink (logically) to 0,.  There may be rare circumstances that it will grow very large if the consumer side lags.

Comment: "Every time that occurs, the copy will be O(n)."
No, you're miscomputing. The first time, you copy one element (if you start from size one), the second time two, and so on, so when n = 2^k the total cost is 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n = 2 * n - 1. The sum has indeed log n addends, but that's it. This material is for instance covered in Cormen et al.

Answer (score 5):

List internally uses an array, so indexing is a direct operation. Also, add at the end is fast (unless a realoc is required). Insert and Remove are O(n) though, because all elements of the array need to be moved around. In practice, this isn't so bad as well, because the move is implemented as a single block-move of the right part of the array.